# Java: Implementing an interfacing by inheriting a class

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, casting

Time-appropriate greetings :)

Working in Java, I have an Interface A. All implementors of this Interface also extend class B, but B does not implement A. In a class where we use an instance of A (referenced as A), it is cast to a B Reference so that we can use a Method defined in class B. It makes sense conceptually that the Method should belong in Interface A too.

Can you think of a reason not to introduce the Method to Interface A, so that we don't have to cast it to B? Should I maybe override the Method in the subclasses and just call the super version, so that it's easier to navigate in the IDE etc?

Comment: Why B doesn't implement A?

Comment: I don't know what the classes actually are, but sounds like it could be solved by redesigning the whole system.

Comment: Throw away the interface A and use only class B.

Comment: The question was why you would not introduce the method to A. The answer is: in good OOP design, you typically want to have small interfaces, according to the single responsibility principle. If your interface defines more methods than for a single responsibility, split it up into two interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In a class where we use an instance of A (referenced as A), it is cast to a B Reference so that we can use a Method defined in class B.

So I'm assuming you have this scenario

```
public void doStuff(A aType){
   ...
   B bType = (B) aType;
   ...
}
```

If this is true, can this work?

```
private <T extends B & A> void example(T type){
    type.aStuff();
    type.doBStuff();
}
```

I created the following to test this.

```
public class Foo{
  private static interface A{ 
    void aStuff();
  }

  private static class B{ 
    public void doBStuff(){ 
        System.out.println("B stuff");
    } 
  }

  private static class AB extends B implements A{
    public void aStuff(){
        System.out.println("A stuff");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.example(new AB());
  }

  // method "example" already given
}
```

Gave me

```
A stuff
B stuff
```

Comment: This might work. I didn't know you could do that. But maybe we should redesign a bit, because it's more complicated than it needs to be. So far I've just repeated the method in the interface. Maybe I'll have a second look and see if there's any real value in having it in both A and B. I actually overrode the method in subclass only to call super because if you search in Eclipse for use of the method in A, you won't see the instances where it's called with a B reference. That's too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating an abstract class which extends B and implements A? Assuming this class would be called C, your other classes would extend C and implement the method required by A, but will provide you with the methods available in B without casting.

I think that moving methods now would not be a good idea, maybe, at most, have B implement A (assuming you have no other classes which you haven't talked about which are dependent on the classes and interfaces you mentioned).

Comment: A is too big and too different for B to implement it, but thanks. I should have explained more in the example...